# Por que uma var do tipo double consegue armazenar uma do tipo int?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Por que uma `var` do tipo `double` consegue armazenar uma `var` do tipo `int`?

Usando C#

```
int x;
double y;

x = 5;
y = 2*x;

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Vamos começar chamar as coisas pelo nome correto, então vamos chamar `x` e `y` de variável, até porque `var` é um comando do C# e usar essa palavra pode confundir do que está falando.

Aí no fim estaria dizendo

> uma variável do tipo `double` consegue armazenar uma variável do tipo `int`

Aí eu vou corrigir o termo mais uma vez, está querendo dizer:

> uma variável do tipo `double` consegue armazenar um valor do tipo `int`

[Variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é uma coisa, valor é outra.

Acontece que não está sendo armazenado um valor do tipo `int` em `y`. O tipo do valor armazenado ali sempre será do tipo `double` porque C# é uma linguagem de tipagem estática e a variável só pode ter um valor do tipo que ela foi declarada. Bem, tem a questão do `null`, mas vamos deixar isso pra lá para não confundir porque nesse caso não pode ter esse valor mesmo.

Então o que aconteceu? Houve um *cast* implícito. Teve uma multiplicação de dois valores do tipo `int` (`2` e `x`) e o resultado disso que também é `int` é convertido automaticamente para um valor do tipo `double`. Então efetivamente uma operação de reconstrução do valor em outro formato é realizado (já que `int` e `double` são **internamente** incompatíveis), mesmo que não pareça ter isso.

A conversão automática é possível só em casos que não tenha perda de dados, e como todo valor de `int` é um valor válido em `double` a conversão é colocada pelo compilador.

Parabéns pela curiosidade, só acostume-se usar termos corretos para se comunicar adequadamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Opa cara, obrigado por estar contribuindo com meu aprendizado. Essa questão da perda de dados eu cheguei a ver no curso que estou fazendo. Mas, para ficar mais claro, o que seria essa perda de dados ?

Comment: Vamos pegar o contrário, você quer armazenar 1.4 que é `double` em uma variável do tipo `int`, então tem que guardar 1 já que só pode armazenar parte decimal nesse tipo, e para onde foi o 0.4? Há uma perda. è permitido fazer isso, mas só manualmente, você tem que dizer que quer a perda, o compilador não faz por você. Se resolveu, você pode aceitar a resposta, veja como é no [tour].

Comment: Então nesse caso posso fazer um casting explicito ? tipo double x = 1.4; int y = (int) x;

Comment: Pode sim, você disse que quer a perda.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado cara.

Comment: @Fluss você leu o [tour]? entendeu o que deve fazer?